# Google sheets query tradelog, trying to find monthly account value of min date of the month to calculate monthly growth %

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to get monthly growth % by trying to find out the account value of the min date of the month and the sum P&L of the month to get the monthly growth rate. But I trying so hard but can’t find the account value for min date of the month here

```
=query(TradeLog!A2:Z, "SELECT V,SUM(P)  GROUP BY V LABEL SUM(P) 'Monthly P&L'")
```

[image: complete spread sheets data]

[image: sample expected data]

Comment: Can you provide the complete sheet sample (column V is missing). Please include the sample expected output as well

Comment: Q2 =IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,A2,A2-WEEKDAY(A2-7)+7)

Comment: Q is just group the same month date in the month, so I can group them by month easier. But now my problem is I can’t find the min of A while group by Q

Comment: I have re upload the complete data and the expected output data, I try many way, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TradeLog!V2:V, TradeLog!P2:P, 
 VLOOKUP(TradeLog!V2:V, {TradeLog!V2:V, TradeLog!Q2:Q}, 2, 0)},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2)/Col3 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col3 
  label sum(Col2)/Col3'' 
  format sum(Col2)/Col3'#.00%'", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It showed REF! “Circular dependency detected. To solve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheets setting”

Comment: I have re upload the complete sheet sample and expected query sample. I tried my best to figure out what can I do, my thought is to have a helper column for the months and sort out the min date in it, but it just doesn’t work. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronTan can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wSsBKY6KcInCjt3dE0VVR-8yRIGYa9EYUFt0W5W5CZA/edit?usp=sharing 
here you go

Comment: It works now! VLOOKUP is the one should apply! Thanks!